# Composing functions in Haskell with arithmetic-type functions

Tags: haskell, function-composition

I'm learning Haskell now and I'm trying to play around with function composition.

I wrote two functions.

`let func1 x y = x + y`

`let func2 t = t*2`

However, when I try to compose these two functions, 
`func2 . func1 1 2` I am expecting to get 6.

Instead, I get this error:

```
   No instance for (Num (a -> b))
      arising from a use of `func1' at <interactive>:1:8-16
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num (a -> b))
    In the second argument of `(.)', namely `func1 1 2'
    In the expression: func2 . func1 1 2
    In the definition of `it': it = func2 . func1 1 2
```

Can someone explain why this is not working?

Comment: `(func2 .) . func1`, or `func2 . func1 1`. To compose with a function taking more than one argument, you need more `(.)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function application has precedence over any operators, so your composition is parsed as `func2 . (func1 1 2)`. That is, your code tries to compose the number that's the result of `func1 1 2` as if it was a function. Note that `(func2 . func1) 1 2` doesn't work either, as `(.)` only works with unary functions.

You *could* use `(func2 . func1 1) 2`, or use `(.)` multiple times in ways that I'm not very comfortable with personally, to tell the truth. But it's probably better to not use composition at all in this specific case: `func2 $ func1 1 2` does the same thing with less clutter.

Answer (score 3):

Due to a lucky mistake (distributive law), you can do this with `Data.Function.on`

```
import Data.Function

func1 x y = x + y
func2 t = t*2

func3 = func1 `on` func2

-- or just func3 = (+) `on` (2*)
```

In general though, you should just use `$` for this sort of thing, since that's what you're doing, function application. This isn't really a job for compose, so you're trying to  jam a square peg into a round hole if you use composition.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is not function composition: You're trying to apply `func1 1 2` to `func2`, that's what the `$` operator is for.

```
func2 $ func1 1 2
```